# Multiplying polynomials/simplifying like terms

Tags: java

Im almost done with a homework assignment that multiplies polynomials and has to have its like terms simplified and in order from highest degree to lowest. The 2 statements are also already sorted. My program works perfectly, but it takes too long to get the result (like 2 minutes on my machine), and the web site i use to submit it says time limit exceeded. For the actual multiplication (not shown here), it takes very little time but the combining of like terms takes a while. It takes in 1 linked list that has 2 statements combined, i.e:

```
2 2 2 1 1 1 //means 2x^2 + 2x +  x
*
3 2 5 1 1 0 //means 3x^2 + 5x + 1
```

and i turn it into 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 2 5 1 1 0 for processing.

Anyone know how i could speed this up a bit? Thanks.

```
    public MyLinkedList add(MyLinkedList combinedList ) {
    MyLinkedList tempCombinedList = new MyLinkedList();
    MyLinkedList resultList = new MyLinkedList();
    //check highest power now that its sorted.
    tempCombinedList=null;
    tempCombinedList = new MyLinkedList();
    int highestPower=0;

    //we need to find highest power
    for(int l=2;l<=combinedList.size();l=l+2) {
        if((Integer)combinedList.get(l)>highestPower) {
            highestPower=(Integer)combinedList.get(l);
            System.out.println("highest power is "+highestPower);
        }
    }

    int tempAddition=0;     
    while(highestPower!=-1) {
        for(int z=2;z<=combinedList.size();z=z+2) {
            if((Integer)combinedList.get(z)==highestPower) {
                tempAddition=tempAddition+(Integer)combinedList.get(z-1);
            }
        }
        if((tempAddition!=0)) { //we arent allowed to have a 0 coefficient in there....
            resultList.add(tempAddition);
            resultList.add(highestPower);
        }
        else if(((tempAddition==0)&&(highestPower==0))) { //unless the exponent is 0 too
            resultList.add(tempAddition);
            resultList.add(highestPower);
        }
        tempAddition=0; //clear the variable for the next roud
        highestPower--; //go down in power and check again.
        }
return resultList;

}
```

Comment: Your title says "adding", but your first sentence says "multiplying".  Which is it?

Comment: Drop in some System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()) and figure out where the time is being spent.

Comment: What is the exact time limit?

Comment: @David, 60 seconds. @Oli Charlesworth i am multiplying, but adding polynomials is the same as simplifying like terms which is required for my output.

Comment: @Evan: Do you mean that you are using this method to "tidy up" the result of multiplication?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, i edited the question to make it more concise, yes, i am using this method to combine like terms and order my result. This is taking the most time while the actual multiplication takes 5-10 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code look like you are using a list with alternating factor and exponent. This is likely not the reason for your performance problem, but makes the code harder to read - additionally to your casting.

Use a class like

```
class Monomial implements Comparable<Monom> {
   private int exponent;
   private int factor;

   // TODO: get methods, constructor

   public int compareTo(Monomial other) {
       return this.exponent - other.exponent;
   }

   public Monomial times(Monomial other) {
      // here your multiplication code
   }


}
```

and then you can have a `List<Monomial>` instead of your list of integers. Firstly, this makes your code more readable, and secondly, you can now (after the multiplication) simply sort your list, so you later don't have to go through the whole list again and again.

Then, as you are always using the `.get(i)` access to your list, don't use a linked list, use an ArrayList (or a similar structure). (For a linked list, you for each access have to iterate through the list to get the element you want, for a array-list not.) Alternatively, use an Iterator (or the enhanced for loop) instead of index-access.

---

Actually, if you sort (and simplify) the factors before multiplying, you can multiply them already in the right sequence so you don't really have to simplify afterwards. As an example, it is

```
(2x^2 + 3x + 0) * (3x^2 + 5x + 1)
= (2*2) * x^4 +
  (2*5  + 3*3) * x^3 +
  (2*1 + 3*5 + 0*3) * x^2 +
  (3*1 + 0*5) * x^1 +
  (0*1) * x^0
= 4 * x^4 + 19 * x^3 + 17 * x^2 + 3 * x
```

(You get the scheme: in each line the factors from the first polynomial are sorted downwards, the ones from the second polynomial upwards).

(And you can leave away the 0 terms already at the beginning, if you want).

Comment: Yes, sorted by degree (like my compareTo method does). So, you have to match the terms from first polynomial with the terms from the second polynomial such that the sum of their degrees are the same. (This is what Oli named "Convolution", look at his link too.)

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying polynomials is equivalent to [convolving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) their coefficients.  There shouldn't be any need to have a separate "simplification" stage.

Convolution is *O(N^2)* time complexity (assuming both polynomials are length *N*).  If *N* is really large, it might be worth considering "fast convolution", which transforms the convolution into an element-wise multiplication via an FFT.  This is *O(N log N)*, although cache issues might kill you in practice.